# Google cloud CDN pricing details on cache data size and automatic cache invalidation

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I was learning about google cloud CDN and is satisfied with the drop in price difference for egress but some info is missing in pricing documentation

- Will cache entries that is automatically removed after expiration of 30 days be charged under $0.005 per cache invalidation section ?
- Is there any cost for amount of data(GB/TB) stored in cache over a period of time ? (eg -> 1TB for 1 month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be charged for cache fill when something is inserted into cache, but there is no charge for ongoing storage space used. There's also no charge for evictions. [cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/pricing#pricing_overview) lists what Cloud CDN charges for:

- Cache egress
- Cache fill
- Cache lookup requests
- Cache invalidation

If it's not listed, Cloud CDN doesn't charge for it. The page notes you'll be "charged for any cache invalidations **you initiate**" [emphasis mine], so you don't need worry about being charged when Cloud CDN evicts a 30-day-old cache entry.